# Running Selenium code on raspberry Pi 24/7

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi

Hi anyone got any pointers on how I would run a selenium python script 24/7?
My code contains a loop and sometimes crashes so need it to keep running.

Comment: This previous answer may help you -- https://superuser.com/a/461560

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/how-do-i-restart-a-python-program-on-my-pi-when-it-crashes